# Lista duplamente ligada em C

Tags: c, lista

Olá, não consigo entender o que há de errado com o código abaixo.
Era pra adicionar um elemento no final da lista ligada, mas nada acontece e tudo compila sem erros.

Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

```
struct cel {
    int info;
    apontador prox;
    apontador ant;
};

typedef struct cel * apontador;


void insereNoFim(int x, apontador lista) {
    apontador aux = lista;

    if (lista == NULL) {
        lista = malloc(sizeof(struct cel));
        lista->info = x;
        lista->ant = lista->prox = NULL;
    }
    else {
        while (aux->prox != NULL) {
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        aux->prox = malloc(sizeof(struct cel));
        aux->prox->info = x;
        aux->prox->ant = aux;
        aux->prox->prox = NULL;
    }  
}
```

Comment: como assim "nada acontece" ? o que era para "acontecer" e não "aconteceu" ? sua pergunta é muito imprecisa

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a função `insereNoFim` recebe o parâmetro `lista` como um valor e não como referência (mesmo que o tipo `apontador` seja um ponteiro). Você poderia receber o parâmetro `lista` como um ponteiro para `apontador`:

```
void insereNoFim(int x, apontador *lista) {
    apontador aux = *lista;

    if (*lista == NULL) {
        *lista = malloc(sizeof(struct cel));
        (*lista)->info = x;
        (*lista)->ant = lista->prox = NULL;
    }
    else {
    ...
```

Ou poderia criar uma função para inicializar uma lista, enquanto que a função `insereNoFim` apenas faria a inserção de valores propriamente dita:

```
apontador iniciarLista(int x){
    apontador lista = malloc(sizeof(struct cel));
    lista->info = x;
    lista->ant = lista->prox = NULL;
}

int insereNoFim(int x, apontador lista) {
    apontador aux = lista;

    if (lista == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        ...
        return 1;
    }  
}
```

Outra possibilidade seria criar um novo tipo, que seria uma estrutura contendo um `apontador`, por exemplo:

```
typedef struct lista{
    apontador inicio;
}*lista;
```

Dessa forma, a função de inicialização seria:

```
lista iniciarLista(void){
    lista novaLista = malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    novaLista->inicio = NULL;
}
```

A função `insereNoFim` ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
int insereNoFim(int x, lista _lista) {
    apontador aux;
    if(_lista == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    aux = _lista->inicio;

    if (aux == NULL) {
        _lista->inicio = malloc(sizeof(struct cel));
        _lista->inicio->info = x;
        _lista->inicio->ant = lista->prox = NULL;
    }
    ...
    return 1;
}
```